# advise on schema design

Tags: sql, schema

I want to store the opening and closing hours of locations into a DB table. Which of the following table design do you think is more ideal? I'm using MySQL or and maybe PostgreSQL (Would it matter?).

One record per day? (returns 1-7 results)

```
id, location_id, weekday, start_time, closing_time
```

Or one record per location? (returns 1 result always)

```
id, location_id, mon_start, mon_end, tue_start, tue_end, ... ... ... sun_start, sun_end
```

The most common query will simply to display the contents like this (always the entire week):

```
Location: blablabla
Operating Hours:
    Monday: 8 AM to 8 PM
    ... ...
    Sunday: 8 AM to 12 PM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution is clearly correct.  The second one is not normalized, harder to program against, and not extendable (for holidays, special hours, etc).

Comment: As an example, with this option, you could have two lots of opening hours per day. (eg: 8am-10am, 4pm-6pm). Try implementing that in your other solution

Comment: The "day" field is actually weekday from 0-6 (Mon to Sun). I have edited the question to reflect this already. I actually don't know what you mean by extending it for holidays.

Comment: In the normalized format, it's easy to add Holiday (or -1 in your system), or other coded values to the system to handle non-standard opening days.  In the denormalized format that requires much more work.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the first, it's better normalised and you could easily produce the data in the second format using a lookup table for the days and perhaps a view.

As the first poster states, the first solution could easily be extended to include holidays, etc. The second is not so flexible.